# How to set default font size in codeblocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I just started using `code::blocks` editor and found that its default font size is smaller to me.Whenever I open it I have to manually resize the font by `settings -> editor -> choose`. What is the way that I make my chosen font size default?

Please don't mark it duplicate or spam as I've checked everywhere to set as default font size but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut by default, but a menu-entry (a little bit hidden).

GOTO:-

> "Edit -> Special Commands -> Zoom -> Reset"

Also, you can assign "any_shortcut" to the menu-entry on the system (using Keybinder-plugin, if you want to).

Hope it helped :)